# How to access the components of a vector-valued interpolating function?

Tags: interpolation, vector

I have a problem in accessing the components of a vector-valued interpolating function. I have the following data:

```
data = {{0, {1, 0}}, {1, {0, 1}}};
```

with a interpolating function

```
ip = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

I can now get the value of `ip` at a given argument, say `0.5` and get:

```
ip[0.5]
```

> ```
> {0.5, 0.5}
> ```

However, if I use  a symbol instead of a number as argument, I get

```
{a, b} - ip[c]
```

> ```
> {a - InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 1}}, <>][c], 
>  b - InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 1}}, <>][c]}
> ```

Now, I can use `Indexed`

```
MapIndexed[#1 - Indexed[ip[c], #2] &, {a, b}]
```

But this seems to be rather complex for such a seemingly simple task.

So I guess what I'm looking for is a way to convert an `InterpolatingFunction` with 'Output dimensions' n into an n-Vector of `InterpolatingFunction` with 'OutputDimensions' 1.

PS:

```
MapIndexed[Indexed[ip[c], #2] &, Range[2]]
```

seems to work. So I just leave this question hoping for a more 'idiomatic' solution.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage over `Indexed` is that the interpolating function is evaluated only once. Having to introduce a dummy variable seems a drawback.

```
vectorEvaluate // ClearAll;
vectorEvaluate // Attributes = {HoldRest};
vectorEvaluate[v_?VectorQ, x_, code_] := Block[{x = v}, code];

data = {{0, {1, 0}}, {1, {0, 1}}};
ip = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
vectorEvaluate[ip[c], v, {a, b} - v]
(*
vectorEvaluate[
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 1}},...][c],
 v, {a, b} - v]
*)

Block[{c = 0.2}, %]
(*  {-0.8 + a, -0.2 + b}  *)
```

Alternatively:

```
vectorEvaluate // ClearAll;
vectorEvaluate // Attributes = {HoldRest};
vectorEvaluate[v_?VectorQ, code_] := Block[{x = v}, code];

vectorEvaluate[ip[c], {a, b} - ip[c]]
```

Here `ip[c]` is evaluated twice, only twice even if `ip[c]` has more than two components.  With `Indexed` as in the OP, `ip[c]` would have to be evaluated as many times as components.