# How to plot each components of InterpolationFunction of dimension {3,3}

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose I solve the following differential equation numerically:

```
s = Flatten@
  NDSolve[{Y'[t] == Y[t], 
    Y[0] == {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}}, 
   Y, {t, 0, 20}]
```

This yields a result in terms of `InterpolatingFunction[]`of dimension `{3,3}` as `Y`is a 3 by 3 matrix.

Now, if I wish to plot each component `Y[[i,j]]` from the solution stored in `s` then how is it possible?

I tried

`Plot[ Evaluate[Y[[1,2]][t]/.s],{t,0,20}]`

for component Y[[1,2]] but it didn't work.

Any idea how to extract each component from the solution `s`and plot?

Comment: Have you seen `Indexed[Y[t], {i, j}]`? See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144480/how-to-access-the-components-of-a-vector-valued-interpolating-function and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126342/nintegrate-of-a-vector-valued-interpolatingfunction-gives-not-numerical/126361#126361

Comment: No, thank you for the links. I will go through it.

Comment: Yes, that works as well.
I have tried this: 
`Plot[Evaluate[Indexed[Y[t], {1, 3}] /. s], {t, 0, 20}]`

Comment: Bingo! Just what I tried. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Indexed` was added to Mathematica to replace `Part` for this sort of problem:

```
s = Flatten@
  NDSolve[{Y'[t] == Y[t], 
    Y[0] == {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}}, 
   Y, {t, 0, 20}]

Plot[Evaluate[Indexed[Y[t], {1, 2}] /. s], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

---

*Update: From @andre314*

```
dimensions = Dimensions[Y[0] /. s];
Plot[Evaluate[Flatten@
  Array[Legended[Indexed[Y[t], {##}], {##}] &, dimensions] /. s],
 {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: While `Indexed[]` appears here and there on the site, I couldn't find a Q&A that asked and answer the OP's question.  Maybe they used to be closed for being in the docs?

Comment: Interestingly, `Indexed` permits to plot all the curves with differents colors and a legend. Example : `dimensions = Dimensions[Y[0] /. s];
Plot[Evaluate[
  Array[Legended[Indexed[Y[t], {#1, #2}], {#1, #2}] &, dimensions] /. 
   s], {t, 0, 20}]`

Comment: If you wish, don't hesitate to copy-paste my code and the resulting graphic (no copyright !)

Comment: @andre314 Thanks! (I added a `Flatten` so they each get different colors.)

Answer (score 2):

```
sValue = Flatten@
  NDSolveValue[{Y'[t] == Y[t], 
    Y[0] == {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}}, 
   Y, {t, 0, 20}]

Plot[Evaluate[sValue[t]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

`NDSolveValue` does exactly the same calculus than `NDSolve`
`Evaluate` is probably useless here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to plot one component instead of all components at a time?

Comment: Yes : `Plot[Evaluate[sValue[t]][[1, 1]], {t, 0, 20}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!